# Convert HTML response to Vue JS component from axiom response (Django)

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js

Fisrt of all sorry for the long question. Since Vue JS performance is very good as compared to some of other platform (Based on test criteria) and easy integrate like a library. I render some html to a span through axiom response. But button (in the response html) click not working and also vue js data also not displaying.

Here is my code

```
 <div id="vue-app" class="container">
    {%csrf_token%}
    <button v-on:click="greet" class="btn btn-primary">BUTTON</button>
    <span v-html="message"></span>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    let app = new Vue({
      el: "#vue-app",
      delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
      data: {
        message: "",
      },
      methods: {
        greet: function (event) {
          let formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value);
          axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: '{% url "core:test_url" %}',
            data: formData
          }).then(
            response => (new Vue.set(this, 'message', response.data))
          );
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
```

Django view

```
class test_func4(View):

    def post(self, request):
        return render(request, 'home/vue_js_axiom.html', {
            "post_to_view": 123
        })
```

vue_js_axiom.html

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="container_in_axiom">
    <tr>
        <td>DATA FROM DJANGO VIEW</td><td>DATA FROM VUE JS</td>
        <td>ON CLICK BUTTON</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{post_to_view}}</td><td>[[vue_js_variable]]</td>
        <td>
            <button v-on:click="click_from_response_view" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">ON CLICK</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
    let container = new Vue({
        el: '#container_in_axiom',
        delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
        data: {
            vue_js_variable: "true",
        },
        methods: {
            click_from_response_view: function (event) {
                alert("clicked from response view");
            }
        },
    });
</script>
```

Can someone help to solve this problem?

1. How can i shorten the FormData like JSON variable as same in Jquery AJAX?
2. How to convert HTML response to Vue JS template from axiom response?
   [image: HTML Layout]

Comment: Try out `this.message= response.data` instead of `new Vue.set(this, 'message', response.data)`

Comment: I have tried that as well